# Maximum Value of XOR in a range?

Tags: java, algorithm, xor

> Given a matrix of size NxN. Rows and Columns are numbered from 0 to
>   N-1. jth column of ith row contains i xor j.   In other words,
>   Matrix[i][j] = i ^ j where 0 ? i,j < N.   Your task is to find the
>   maximum value occurring in this matrix and the count of its
>   occurrence.

While my approach was

```
(l..r).each do |i|
    (i..r).each do |j|
      if (i ^ j > max)
        max = i ^ j
      end
    end
  end
```

I saw this code which says it according to everyone is not quadratic is finding it in linear time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        long N;
        long max    = 1L;
        long count  = 1L;
        long bitN   ;
        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder(4*T);


            line = br.readLine();
            N = Long.parseLong(line);
            {

                bitN    = 1L << getBits(N-1);
                max     = (bitN - 1);
                count   = (bitN == N) ? bitN :(N -(bitN>>1))<<1 ;

                sb.append(max);
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(count);
                sb.append("\n");
            }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

    private static int getBits(long x){
        int count = 0;
        while(x > 0){
            x = x>>1;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

What i'm unable to understand is how is this actually

```
bitN    = 1L << getBits(N-1);
max     = (bitN - 1);
count   = (bitN == N) ? bitN :(N -(bitN>>1))<<1 ;
```

able to get the desired result. If anyone of you could just give me basic of this algorithm in simple terms so that i can understand this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a table of `N` versus `max` and `count`:

```
N   max   count   how
1     0       1   0^0
2     1       2   0^1, 1^0
3     3       2   1^2, 2^1
4     3       4   1^2, 2^1, 0^3, 3^0
5     7       2   3^4, 4^3
6     7       4   3^4, 4^3, 2^5, 5^2
7     7       6   3^4, 4^3, 2^5, 5^2, 1^6, 6^1
8     7       8   3^4, 4^3, 2^5, 5^2, 1^6, 6^1, 0^7, 7^0
9    15       2   7^8, 8^7
.
.
```

The pattern is that, after `N` crosses a power of two, the `max` goes up and the `count` goes back to `2`. This is because the bit patterns look like this:

```
3 = 0b011
4 = 0b100
.
.
7 = 0b0111
8 = 0b1000
```

`bitN` is the lowest bit set nowhere in `0..N-1` (so `bitN = 8` when `N = 8`, and `bitN = 16` when `N = 9`). The maximum XOR has all bits below `bitN` set, which is `bitN - 1` by the logic of borrowing in grade-school subtraction. The count goes up two every time `N` increases by one except when `bitN` increases as well, when the count resets to two. The purpose of the ternary operator in computing `count` is to special case `N = 1`; the left branch is also taken when `N` is a greater power of two, but the other would work as well.